# How to target the publication lists in query activity?

Tags: marketing-cloud

I need to check the status in all subscribers and then update the status in publication lists using a query. How can I directly target publication lists in the query activity?

Or do I need to get the data in a data extension and then use import activity to update the publication lists?

Answer (score 2):

The latter.  You can't update System Data View data with a Query Activity.  It's a read-only view.  You'll have to export the results in a Data Extension to a file and import it into the List or Publication.  Steps in the Automation would be:

1. [**Query Activity**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/automation_studio/using_automation_studio_activities/using_the_query_activity/) to select subscribers to update
2. Export the Data Extension to a file using a [**Data Extract**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/automation_studio/using_automation_studio_activities/use_a_data_extract_activity/) activity
3. Import the file with an [**Import Activity**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/import_activity/)

Comment: Instead, we can use SSJS also in the automation to update the publication list.  Right? @Adam Spriggs

Comment: Yes, you could use a Script Activity.  You're limited to working with 2500 rows at a time and also a strict 30 minute timeout window..